# Best way to optimize and merge these Jquery functions

Tags: jquery, performance, dry

I have 3 functions that are all set with click events that trigger the same functions within their respective divs. I'd like to optimize this so I'm not repeating myself over and over. What would be the best way to write this?

```
//Progress Bar animation when tab clicked
$('#tab1').click(function () {
    $('#stack .progress div').each(function () {
        var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
        if (nextValue == '0') {
            $(display).css('padding', '0');
        } else {
            $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
                'width': nextValue + '%'
            }, 'slow');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                currentValue += step
                display.html(currentValue + '%');
            }, 20 * i);
        }
    })
});
$('#tab2').click(function () {
    $('#design .progress div').each(function () {
        var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
        if (nextValue == '0') {
            $(display).css('padding', '0');
        } else {
            $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
                'width': nextValue + '%'
            }, 'slow');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                currentValue += step
                display.html(currentValue + '%');
            }, 20 * i);
        }
    })
});
$('#tab3').click(function () {
    $('#other .progress div').each(function () {
        var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
        if (nextValue == '0') {
            $(display).css('padding', '0');
        } else {
            $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
                'width': nextValue + '%'
            }, 'slow');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                currentValue += step
                display.html(currentValue + '%');
            }, 20 * i);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I prefer burning one thing in one oven.* If you need to change one thing, you should need to change it at one place.

```
function doAnimation() {
    var display = $(this),
    currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
    nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
    diff = nextValue - currentValue,
    step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
    if (nextValue == '0') {
        $(display).css('padding', '0');
    } else {
        $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
            'width': nextValue + '%'
        }, 'slow');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            currentValue += step
            display.html(currentValue + '%');
        }, 20 * i);
    }
}
//Progress Bar animation when tab clicked
$('#tab1').click(function () {
    $('#stack .progress div').each(doAnimation);
});
$('#tab2').click(function () {
    $('#design .progress div').each(doAnimation);
});
$('#tab3').click(function () {
    $('#other .progress div').each(doAnimation);
});
```

Comment: This is generating the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Comment: Although there I knew there were multiple ways of doing what I wanted, this seemed to make it pretty cut and dry and did not require adding any additional type tags on my view. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add a data attribute to the HTML tags representing the tab. For instance:

```
data-progress="#stack"

data-progress="#design"

data-progress="#other"
```

Define a function, like this:

```
function tabClicked() {
    $($(this).data("progress") + ' .progress div').each(function () {
        var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
        if (nextValue == '0') {
            $(display).css('padding', '0');
        } else {
            $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
                'width': nextValue + '%'
            }, 'slow');
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                currentValue += step
                display.html(currentValue + '%');
            }, 20 * i);
        }
    });
}
```

And use it as a click handler:

```
$("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3").click(tabClicked);
```

Comment: This is pretty, can I ask why you would add the 'data-progress' attribute? Wouldn't it work just fine without since the tabs already have an href with the same id reference?

Comment: @JuanPabloUgas, that's a good question. The data-progress attribute was added because the three separate functionalities used different selectors in that .each() call at the start of the function and on functionality level I believe it is more elegant to be agnostic to selectors and to use $(this).data("progress") instead. The .data() call can work if and only if we define the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
var progressTargets = {tab1 : "stack", tab2 : "design", tab3 : "other"};
$('#tab1, #tab2, #tab3').click(function () {
    $("#"+progressTargets[$(this).attr("id")]+' .progress div').each(function () {
        var display = $(this),
        currentValue = parseInt(display.text()),
        nextValue = $(this).attr('data-values'),
        diff = nextValue - currentValue,
        step = (0 < diff ? 1 : -1);
        if (nextValue == '0') {
            $(display).css('padding', '0');
        } else {
            $(display).css('color', '#fff').animate({
                'width': nextValue + '%'
            }, 'slow');
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(diff); ++i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                currentValue += step
                display.html(currentValue + '%');
            }, 20 * i);
        }
    });
});
```

try using array to target relevant progress bars.